# Question Uncountable Set Binary Sequence Notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, infinity

In class, my professor mentioned that $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ was uncountable, and I completely understand the argument. However, I am confused because others online gave a similar proof of $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1)$ which are the numbers between 0 and 1.

What I really need to know is isn't the codomain of $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ only $0$ and $1$? So shouldn't it only map to a single element $0$ or $1$? In that case wouldn't this be countable?

Please explain!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for any function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, the codomain is just the set of two elements $0$ and $1$.

However, a function in and of itself is not uncountable ... or even countable. That's just a category mistake. *Sets* are countable or uncountable.

So, what *set* are we dealing with here?  I see $\mathbb{N}$, which is obviously countable. I see $\{ 0,1 \}$, which is obviously countable. And I see $(0,1)$, which is not countable.

But, what your professor probably meant is that the *set of all functions* that map natural numbers to $\{ 0,1\}$ (i.e. the set of all functions of the form $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$) is an uncountable set.

And why exactly is that set uncountable?  Here you can use the standard diagonal argument that I assume you were given by your professor as well. But let me give the argument myself; maybe I present it in a way that's a little different from your professor.

OK, so the proof is a proof by contradiction. Let's assume the set of all functions of the form $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ is countable.  Well, that means that you can number them, i.e. you have a $f_1$, $f_2$ .. etc., and every function is supposed to be on that list. That is, for every function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{ 0,1 \}$, we have that $g = f_i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, that's all a little abstract, so let's think of some actual functions that map $\mathbb{N}$ to $ \{0,1\}$. Here is one: the function that maps every number to $0$. Another one is one that maps all numbers to $1$. Another one is one that maps all even numbers to $0$, and all odd numbers to $1$. Etc. etc.  Anyway, maybe in our enumeration of all functions, the first three functions I mention here end up in the first three positions. That is, maybe we have $f_1(n)=0$ for all $n$, $f_2(n)=1$ for all $n$, and $f_3(n) = n \mod 2$ for all $n$.

Now, we can represent these functions on an infinite table like so:

\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&...\\
\hline
f_1&0&0&0&0&0&...\\
f_2&1&1&1&1&1&...\\
f_3&0&1&0&1&0&...\\
...\\
\end{array}

OK, but now consider the function  $g: \mathbb{N} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ defined as $g(n) = 1 - f_n(n)$. Clearly $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{ \{ 0,1 \}$, and so it should be $f_k$ for some $k$. However, you then get $f_k(k) = g(k) = 1-f_k(k)$, a contradiction, given that $f(n) \not = 1 - f(n)$ for any $f$ or $n$.

This is called the diagonal method, because the 'new' function $g$ is constructed by taking the diagonal of the above table, and systematically changing each entry to something different:

\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&...\\
\hline
f_1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&...\\
f_2&1&\color{red}0&1&1&1&...\\
f_3&0&1&\color{red}1&1&0&...\\
...\\
\end{array}

And so, since the $k$-th element of this new function $g$ is different from the $k$-th element from $f_k$, it cannot be any of the $f_k$'s.

Comment: Could you explain why it's uncountable? Still it's not very clear to me

Comment: @AlirezaFirouzja I thought you said you 'completely understand the argument'?

Comment: I did, but now that you explained it like that it's not clear anymore

Comment: I'm not sure how a set can be uncountable if I can only get 0 and 1 from the output

Comment: @AlirezaFirouzja Ah!  OK, well, it's the standard diagonal argument that I assume you were given. If you assume the set of all functions of the form $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ is countable, then you can number them, i.e. you have a $f_1$, $f_2$ .. etc.  OK, but then consider the function  $g: \mathbb{N} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ defined as $g(n) = 1 - f_n(n)$. Clearly $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{ \{ 0,1 \}$, but it cannot be any of the functions $f$, for if it was, it would be $f_k$ for some $k$, but then you get $f_k(k) = g(k) = 1-f_k(k)$, a contradiction.

Comment: @AlirezaFirouzja Again, don't think about this as a single function ... or merely focus on its codomain. The claim is about *all* functions of this kind ... of which there are many. For example: the function that maps every number to $0$ is one such function. Another one is one that maps all numbers to $1$. Another one is one that maps all even numbers to $0$, and all odd numbers to $1$. Another one is .... etc. etc.  In fact, there are so many that they form an uncountable set.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A function  $f\colon A\to B$ is a function that for each element of $A$ outputs an element of $B$, but of course not necessarily the same output for all inputs. Hence a function $\Bbb N\to \{0,1\}$ outputs either $0$ or $1$ for a given natural number $n$, but the value may of course depend on $n$.

Also note that it is not (a single function) $\Bbb N\to \{0,1\}$ that is uncountable, but rather the *set* of all such functions.

Btw, the set of function $\Bbb N\to (0,1)$ is already uncountable because $(0,1)$ itself is; so even the *constant* maps $\Bbb N\to(0,1)$ are an uncountable set.